# Meteor - installing meteorite gives an error

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to install Meteor package manager - Meteorite.

When I do "npm install -g meteorite", I get the following errors.

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt/0.2.3
npm ERR! git clone git://github.com/possibilities/ws.git execvp(): No such file or directory
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/lib'
npm ERR! error rolling back  meteorite@0.4.3 { [Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/lib']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -1,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/node_modules/fstream/lib' }
npm ERR! Error: `git "clone" "git://github.com/possibilities/ws.git" "/var/root/tmp/npm-1056/1351683071807-0.13464537682011724"` failed with 127
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:56:20)
.........
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solved the problem, but I have Macbook Air with Mountain Lion. But I didn't update my old XCode until now. I updated it because I needed SVN.

I'm not sure if this fixed the problem, but I just tried npm install -g meteorite and it worked fine. There must be some dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I tried and can't replicate the error.

Tried both `npm install -g meteorite` and `npm install meteorite`

Do you have git correctly installed and in the correct path?

Comment: I think this is most likely it: This is a bug in npm really.